# Cannot perform Symbolic Link with Splunk and Linux

Tags: symlink

I am using Splunk with Linux currently.

For the last few days, I cannot execute the following:
[image]

Can you please help as I need to execute this Symbolic link?

Many thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the user you're running `yarn` as has the permissions necessary to create a symlink to that path.